# create pairings of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

   a       b      c     d
0 1.23   -1.25  0.15   1.41
1 0.64   -0.16  0.46   -1.06
2 -0.98  0.54   -0.81  0.33
3 1.71   0.95   1.01   -0.81
```

How can I create a dataframe with all possible column pairs?

```
p1  p2    c1     c2
a   b    1.23   -1.25
a   b    0.64   -0.16
a   b    -0.98  0.54
a   b    1.71   0.95
a   c    1.23   0.15
a   c    0.64   0.46
a   c    -0.98  -0.81
a   c    1.71   1.01
... ...  ...   ...
c   d    0.15   1.41
c   d    0.46   -1.06
c   d    -0.81  0.33
c   d    1.01   -0.81
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- get all combination of columns by `itertools`:
- get list of all combinations by list comprehension and and rename columns:
  (`df[[x[0], x[1]]]` is for first pair `df[['a', 'b']]`)
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` for `Multiindex`
- last some data cleaning - remove 3rd level, new columns names

---

```
from  itertools import combinations
cc = list(combinations(df.columns,2))

dfs = [df[[x[0], x[1]]].rename(columns={x[0]:'c1', x[1]:'c2'}) for x in cc]
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, keys=cc)
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=2, drop=True).rename_axis(('p1','p2')).reset_index()
print (df1)
   p1 p2    c1    c2
0   a  b  1.23 -1.25
1   a  b  0.64 -0.16
2   a  b -0.98  0.54
3   a  b  1.71  0.95
4   a  c  1.23  0.15
5   a  c  0.64  0.46
6   a  c -0.98 -0.81
7   a  c  1.71  1.01
8   a  d  1.23  1.41
9   a  d  0.64 -1.06
10  a  d -0.98  0.33
11  a  d  1.71 -0.81
12  b  c -1.25  0.15
13  b  c -0.16  0.46
14  b  c  0.54 -0.81
15  b  c  0.95  1.01
16  b  d -1.25  1.41
17  b  d -0.16 -1.06
18  b  d  0.54  0.33
19  b  d  0.95 -0.81
20  c  d  0.15  1.41
21  c  d  0.46 -1.06
22  c  d -0.81  0.33
23  c  d  1.01 -0.81
```

Comment: Glad can help! Really interesting problem, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the combinations in terms of two you can use `itertools.combinations` of columns then cumcount() to get the index. Hope it helps

```
import itertools

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

r = list(itertools.combinations(df.columns.tolist(), 2))

new = pd.DataFrame(list(r*df.shape[0]),columns=['p1','p2']).sort_values(['p1','p2']).reset_index(drop=True)

new['count'] = new.groupby(['p1','p2']).cumcount()

new['c1'] = new.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x['count'],x['p1']],axis=1)
new['c2'] = new.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x['count'],x['p2']],axis=1)

new = new.drop('count',axis=1)
```

Output :

```
   p1 p2        c1        c2
0   a  b -0.157408 -0.293641
1   a  b -0.205898 -0.527494
2   a  b -0.740385  1.058200
3   a  b  2.163202  0.584529
4   a  c -0.157408  0.824047
5   a  c -0.205898  0.016703
.
.
.
22  c  d  0.260635 -0.958339
23  c  d -0.641043 -1.199849
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your data frame isn't too large, a nested loop works well enough:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

print(df)
          a         b         c         d
0  0.004477 -0.367254 -0.251733 -0.957313
1  0.996096  0.879603  1.499766  0.386398
2 -0.459716  0.186510  0.738449 -0.219747
3  0.606211  0.077233  1.583994  0.824706

master = pd.DataFrame()
known_pairs = []
n = df.shape[0]

for p1 in df:
    for p2 in df:
        pair = sorted((p1,p2))
        if (p1 != p2) & (pair not in known_pairs):
            known_pairs.append(sorted((p1,p2)))
            tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.array([p1,p2] * n).reshape(n, 2), columns=['p1','p2'])
            tmp['c1'] = df[p1]
            tmp['c2'] = df[p2]
            master = pd.concat([master, tmp])

print(master)
  p1 p2        c1        c2
0  a  b  0.004477 -0.367254
1  a  b  0.996096  0.879603
2  a  b -0.459716  0.186510
3  a  b  0.606211  0.077233
0  a  c  0.004477 -0.251733
1  a  c  0.996096  1.499766
2  a  c -0.459716  0.738449
3  a  c  0.606211  1.583994
0  a  d  0.004477 -0.957313
1  a  d  0.996096  0.386398
2  a  d -0.459716 -0.219747
3  a  d  0.606211  0.824706
0  b  c -0.367254 -0.251733
1  b  c  0.879603  1.499766
2  b  c  0.186510  0.738449
3  b  c  0.077233  1.583994
0  b  d -0.367254 -0.957313
1  b  d  0.879603  0.386398
2  b  d  0.186510 -0.219747
3  b  d  0.077233  0.824706
0  c  d -0.251733 -0.957313
1  c  d  1.499766  0.386398
2  c  d  0.738449 -0.219747
3  c  d  1.583994  0.824706
```